# Changing the proxy server during Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, updates

So everything works

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
fp.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

But if the driver has already been created, the proxy can not install.
It does not work

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
driver.profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
driver.profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
driver.profile.update_preferences()
```

And so, too.

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
 driver.firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", PROXY_HOST)
 driver.firefox_profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PROXY_PORT))
 driver.firefox_profile.update_preferences()
```

Why? Can not understand.
I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, which one? Does the web driver just ignore your new proxy settings?

Comment: No. No errors. Everything works correctly. But the settings are not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using WebDriver with Firefox, the use of the profile is a one-time thing. When the driver launches the browser, it writes the profile object to disk, then starts the browser executable. After that point, there is no mechanism for the browser to read any further changes to the WebDriver profile object. To change the proxy, you have to set the settings in the profile before the browser is launched.