# Python Selenium Firefox not Configuring Proxy

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, proxy, python-3.6

I've tried all the most current and previous ways people have tried to configure fire fox here in stack overflow, and I've been reading all the [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#firefox-up-to-version-47-0-1).
There aren't may answers that have given a definitive way to configure the proxies for firefox that many people agree on. The most recent was with a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39791242/changing-the-proxy-server-during-selenium) asked that pointed that the initial way he did it successfully configured the proxy but when I tried it, I am returned with AttributeError.

```html
from selenium import webdriver

IP = "###.###.###.###"
PORT = "####"

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http", IP)
fp.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(PORT))
fp.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver.get('http://www.my-ip-address.net/')
```

The above code seems to me the most currently used and recent but its still giving me errors.

I've tried several variations of int() and str() on IP and PORT, but nothing seemed to work.

I cannot find any documentation that seems to be current. If anyone can refer me to something currently working I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: Code works perfectly on my machine, how did you check that proxy is not being set?  can you just check in the firefox opened by selenium.

Comment: It won't open so I can't check and I get this error instead: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/Dropbox/Programing/YT Bot/testfirefoxproxy.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
  File "C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 126, in __init__
    if isinstance(firefox_profile, types.StringTypes):
AttributeError: module 'types' has no attribute 'StringTypes'

Comment: are you running a different version of python?

Comment: I just tried it on python 2.7, are you using a different version of firefox? @GaurangShah

Comment: could you update the question with Error you are getting, Firefox and Selenium version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several questions and answers here that are do work, however, if they don't work for you here are the reasons why configuring proxies via Firefox work for them and not you.

1. Be sure that you have a version of python 2.
      All those ways started to work when I set up a virtual env and installed python 2.7.9. Any python 2 version should work.
2. Be sure you have firefox version 47
      For some reasons selenium documentation with configurations to setting up proxies are outdated and don't work for any version of python 3.5 and up.

If you have these two set up the above code should work just fine.