# Selenium WebDriver - how to get proxy used?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, http-proxy

I use Selenium WebDriver in Python to do web scraping and I often change the proxy and user-agent.

I need to know, at any time during my code execution, which parameters my WebDriver is using.

I know how to get user-agent with:

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
```

But I can't find the way to get the proxy being used. Is there something like ?:

```
driver.execute_script("return navigator.proxy;")
```

Comment: Relevant ==> ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/39810577/6241235

Comment: Thanks, but it does not solve my problem. I need to check which proxy is being used by my current web browser instance. I don't need to change the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

for java and chrome

```
    options.addArguments("--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:"+proxyPort);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.getCapabilities().merge(options);//need to appear socks in Capabilities
```

next in code

```
    UnmodifiableIterator iterator=((ImmutableList)((((TreeMap)((ChromeDriver) driver).getCapabilities().asMap().get("goog:chromeOptions")).get("args")))).iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        String data=(String) iterator.next();
        if (data.contains("proxy")) {
            return data;
        }
    }
```